# How to Create a Vector Field from Separate u and v Data Files?

Tags: qgis, vector, netcdf

I am using Quantum GIS and trying to create a vector field using data from two separate netcdfs. One contains the u data, one contains the v data. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: What is u and v data?

Comment: *u* and *v* are the [vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) components along the *x* and *y* directions; see [zonal and meridional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonal_and_meridional)

Comment: @User could you please explain what it would mean to "create" a vector field? Do you want to depict one (perhaps as a collection of arrows on a map)? Or interpolate samples of one onto a grid? Or perhaps create some kind of native QGIS vector field data type for further analysis?

Comment: Yes, in this case I simply want to render a collection of arrows on a map for visual purposes only. I will be overlaying the current vectors (arrows) on a temperature map. I had been using IDV for this, but I am having compatibility issues at the moment. I have zero experience with qgis. It looks like a very promising application though.

Comment: This question is old, but just in case: there is now a plugin for that: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorFieldRenderer/

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing, and after some searching found a nice tutorial for how to do this:

http://marine.copernicus.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/1-QGIS_TO_USE_CMEMS_INFORMATION_level2.pdf

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take the tour. Also summarize what is in your link in case it disappears in the future.

Comment: The plug in here no longer seems to exist sadly.